# AWS Rekognition limits on collections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

If I was using **IndexFaces**, you need to supply a image and a collection id that will then add the faces in the image to the collection id specified. Lets say I gave a collection id on a collection that contains one million faces, which is the limit of collections in `AWS` `Rekognition`. Therefore adding more faces to this collection would throw an error (I think) cause then this would surpass the limit of one million faces in the collection. So I was wondering what error would be thrown by **IndexFaces** and/or how to tell on AWS rekognition the number of faces in my collection? I have listed the error list below for **IndexFaces** in case it helps.

> AccessDeniedException You are not authorized to perform the action.
>
> ImageTooLargeException The input image size exceeds the allowed limit. For more information, see Limits in Amazon Rekognition.
>
> InternalServerError Amazon Rekognition experienced a service issue. Try your call again.
>
> InvalidImageFormatException The provided image format is not supported.
>
> InvalidParameterException Input parameter violated a constraint. Validate your parameter before calling the API operation again.
>
> InvalidS3ObjectException Amazon Rekognition is unable to access the S3 object specified in the request.
>
> ProvisionedThroughputExceededException The number of requests exceeded your throughput limit. If you want to increase this limit, contact Amazon Rekognition.
>
> ResourceNotFoundException Collection specified in the request is not found.
>
> ThrottlingException Amazon Rekognition is temporarily unable to process the request. Try your call again.

Comment: I would guess ResourceLimitExceeded, despite it not being documented.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what error would cause, but what I do is to count the number of faces in a collection in the following way:

```
$list = $this->client->listFaces([
    'CollectionId' => 'nombrecoleccion',
]);

$substr = substr($list, 294);
$json = json_decode($substr);
$result = $json->{'Faces'};
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
     $faces[$i] = $result[$i]->{'FaceId'};
}
count($faces);
```